# How can I outsource the method of a menu to a separate class?

Tags: java, swing

Yesterday I started Coding a program in Java Swing. Before I coded only small console programs in java.

I put the main menu of the program in a different class than the main method. Now I wanted to add a button for an options menu and also put the code it executes into a class of its own, so that in the main menu class I only have to call the options menu method.

And here I get stuck. If I write the code for the options menu directly in the class of the main menu everything works. But as soon as I outsource the method of the options menu to a separate class, I cannot call the outsourced method.

Perhaps you can help me.

Here is the code that shall be performed when hitting the options button:

```
public class CPP_Frame extends JFrame {

        JButton SettingsButton = new JButton("Options");
        SettingsButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                CPP_Frame OptionsMenu = new CPP_Frame();
                OptionsMenu.OptionsMenuLoader();
            }
        });
    }
```

And that´s the code inside the Options Menu-class that shall be called by the 'OptionsMenuLoader':

```
public class Options_Menu extends JFrame {

    protected void OptionsMenuLoader() {
        CPP_Frame OptionsMenu = new CPP_Frame();
        OptionsMenu.setSize(new Dimension(400, 500));
        OptionsMenu.setVisible(true);
        OptionsMenu.setTitle("Options");
        OptionsMenu.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Where do I mistaken or is the way I try to write the code even possible.
I hope I´ve explained my problem detailed enough.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please provide your entire program. Anyway, I would suggest to you to read a tutorial about inheritance, overriding, polymorphism, abstraction, encapsulation, interfaces and packages  in Java and when and how to use. You may start here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_inheritance.htm You also should read about what a constructor is, found here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_constructors.htm

Comment: Your application should have one and only one JFrame.  You can create multiple JPanels to display different things.  You can also use JDialogs.

Comment: The code in your question does not compile. I think you should read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) If you use [java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) it will make it easier for others to read and understand your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see a couple potential issues here, and I'm not overly knowledgeable about swing so correct me if I am wrong, I'm just looking at this from a programming point of view

Firstly `OptionsMenuLoader()` is declared as a protected method. This means if can only be called by methods in the same class as it, or classes that are derived from it.

Therefor to call `OptionsMenuLoader` it must either be in the same class as the `actionPerformed` override, or CPP_Frame would have to inherit Options_Menu, which from your structure I imagine would be wrong.

If this is possible with-in the format of a swing one solution would be to make 'OptionsMenuLoader()' public

```
    public void OptionsMenuLoader(){
        ...
    }
```

Secondly i'm not sure why this does not produce an error, you call `OptionsMenuLoader()` on `OptionsMenu`, while this looks right you declared the `OptionsMenu` as a `CPP_Frame` rather than as an `Options_Menu` type. This shouldn't work because `CPP_Fram`e has no such method `OptionsMenuLoader()`.

I think what you are aiming to do is create a CPP frame that contains an Options Menu. Which is created when the button in a different CPP Frame is clicked.

In this case you would have to create an `Options_Menu` on action, not a CPP Frame. You can then call the `OptionsMenu.OptionsMenuLoader()` method on this new menu.

```
public class CPP_Frame extends JFrame {

        JButton SettingsButton = new JButton("Options");
        SettingsButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                Options_Menu OptionsMenu = new Options_Menu();
                OptionsMenu.OptionsMenuLoader();
            }
        });
    }
```

```
public class Options_Menu extends JFrame {

    public void OptionsMenuLoader() {
        CPP_Frame OptionsMenu = new CPP_Frame();
        OptionsMenu.setSize(new Dimension(400, 500));
        OptionsMenu.setVisible(true);
        OptionsMenu.setTitle("Options");
        OptionsMenu.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this extensive answer. This helped me understanding my issue. You were right. This fixed the issue. Thank you very much. But about the 'protected': I was using it because - at least this is how I learned it - the access level of protected is the class, package and subclass. The Options_Menu and the CPP_Frame class are in the same package, so I thought I could use protected.

Comment: In terms of using protected if the code works with that method having protected access then I'd imagine you are probably right on that one. Honestly I've rarely found a reason to actually need to use protected methods so I don't know everything about them.